# Delay loading gif and fade in appended data

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#load-extmsg-1').click(function(){
$("#stars").empty().html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader2.gif" id="loadingpic" style="width:25px;height:25px;border:0px;margin-left:48px;margin-top:0px;" />');
$.post('starproc.asp?picid=<%=picid%>&starrating=1', function(data){
$("#loadingpic").remove();
$("#stars").append(data);
})
});
});
```

JQuery works, but how do I make the loading gif stay for 1 sec and then fade in the appended data ?

Here's the code that's working after a little trial and error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#load-extmsg-1').click(function(){
$("#stars").empty().html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader2.gif" id="loadingpic" style="width:25px;height:25px;border:0px;margin-left:48px;margin-top:0px;" />').fadeIn(200).delay(300);
$.post('starproc.asp?picid=<%=picid%>&starrating=1', function(data){
$("#loadingpic").fadeOut(300).delay(200);
$("#stars").append(data);
})
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#stars").fadeOut().delay(200).append(data).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
```

==

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#load-extmsg-1').click(function(){
$("#stars").empty().html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader2.gif" id="loadingpic" style="width:25px;height:25px;border:0px;margin-left:48px;margin-top:0px;" />');
$.post('starproc.asp?picid=<%=picid%>&starrating=1', function(data){
$("#loadingpic").remove();
    $("#stars").fadeOut().delay(200).append(data).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
})
});
});
```

Comment: could you add that into the existing code? No idea where I'm supposed to stick that or replace existing code. Thanks

Comment: Nope. On submit, the gif loads then disappears quickly, then the div fadesout then the data is appended.

Comment: Already did. Tried again just now. The gif loads, disappears, then the div fades out then the gif fades back in with it, the the data is appended.

Comment: Got it! .fadeIn(200).delay(300); on the end of the html and .fadeOut(300).delay(200); on the end of $("#loadingpic")

Comment: that's what I have given. however I see no reason for delay at the end

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
var postMyData = function(){
    $.post('starproc.asp?picid=<%=picid%>&starrating=1', function(data){
        $("#stars").animate({opacity:0},200,function(){
            $("#loadingpic").remove();
            $(this).append(data).animate({opacity:1},200);;
        });
    });
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load-extmsg-1').click(function(){
        var h = '<img src="/images/ajax-loader2.gif" id="loadingpic" style="width:25px;height:25px;border:0px;margin-left:48px;margin-top:0px;" />';        
        $("#stars").animate({opacity:0},200,function(){
            $(this).empty().html(h).animate({opacity:1},200,function(){ postMyDate(); });
        });
    });
});
```

this will work, if not, tell to more help.